# How can I find out if my compiled C++ DLL is used in an IDE?

Tags: c++, ide, activex

We have developed a C++ ActiveX DLL which is now to be sold.

We would like to implement a licensing scheme like VB6's *.lic* files for OCX components. The idea is that a developer who uses our library in their project needs a license file which is automatically checked for validity if the ActiveX component determines that it is used in an IDE.

How can I find this out in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE's which support ActiveX design-time licensing do so by calling your `IClassFactory2::CreateInstanceLic` and passing `NULL` for the `bstrKey` parameter. Feel free to handle that any way you like. You can't detect an IDE which doesn't cooperate.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me to the right direction, [Licensing ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751973(v=vs.85).aspx)